# Android time picker

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have used the code on [this Android developers page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) to create a time picker when a button is pressed. However, I'm not getting the right look for it. I'm targeting my app to API 18 and the minimum is 10, because I want to support 2.3 due to the [high usage](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform). The minimum required SDK doesn't seem to have effect on the problem (I set it to 16):

I'm debugging the application on my HTC One S with Android 4.1.2, API 16. I get this kind of time picker but I want it to look modern, like in the Android developers page linked earlier.

http://www.b2creativedesigns.com/Tutorials/TimePicker/tutorial_timepicker2.png

Why does it use this prehistoric looking time picker?

I create the dialog using the following snippet. I call it from a FragmentActivity.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(2);
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "endtime");
```

This is the code for `TimePickerFragment`.

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    private static int id;

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(int _id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", _id);

        id = _id;

        TimePickerFragment f = new TimePickerFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        id = getArguments().getInt("id");

        int hour = start / 60;  // start is a global variable, no problems in these
        int minute = start % 60;

        if(id == 2) {
            hour = end / 60;
            minute = end % 60;
        }

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        System.out.println(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        setTime(id, hourOfDay, minute);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly because you seem to be using a non holo activity theme.

Comment: It might be HTC's TimePicker UI.. try running the app in an emulator and see what happens...

Comment: @A--C I have used http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ to generate some simple theme for my application. My apps theme is set to the custom one in the manifest file, but the parent of the theme is set to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`.

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r No, it's not. I get the same result on Nexus 7.

Comment: Please add some relevant code. Especially, what is the Context you're passing to the picker.

Comment: @laalto Added some code snippets!

Comment: @laalto It seems that creating the dialog from FragmentActivity creates this kind of result. If I run the dialog from a normal Activity, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) to explicitly provide your Holo-based theme for the `Dialog`, e.g.

```
return new TimePickerDialog(
        new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.YourAppStyleInheritingFromHolo),
        this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

Comment: Awesome job! I will award you the bounty as soon as I can!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Holo theme for the Holo widgets to work in your app. For example :

in your Manifest, under application :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and in your res/values folder :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
</style>
```

while using this in values-v11 and values-v14 :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

The system will switch between Theme.Light and Theme.Holo.Light depending on the Android version on the device.

Comment: AppBaseTheme's parent is set to my own theme, which parent is android:Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: I just tested this on a Galaxy S3 running 4.1 and HTC One running 4.2, both show a Holo Time Picker. Are the other parts of your app looking old as well ?

Comment: Every other part is looking like they should. I haven't tried to debug on an emulator, why won't my real devices be fine?

Comment: Deleted the part about the emulator, sorry, just read your comment about having the same result on Nexus 7... I asked about the other parts of your app because the set time button you have under the dialog looks very GingerBread as well. If you're not changing the theme programmatically, and every vales folder contains the right theme, I'm afraid I out of ideas. Maybe post your styles.xml inside the values-v11 and values-v14 ...

Comment: Haha, you looked at the picture too closely! I just googled Android timepicker, and that was one of the images I found. Just the time picker looks the same.

Comment: Additionally, besides posting the styles.xml, what are you using for android:theme inside the Manifest ?

Comment: styles.xml: http://pastebin.com/7iqPuWDg styles_silence.xml: http://pastebin.com/LQWAZe2J `android:theme="@style/Theme.Silence"`

Comment: Have you tried renaming styles_silence.xml to themes.xml or defining Theme.Silence directly in styles.xml ? This is weird :/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this library. It is a backported TimePicker from Android 4.2 which works from android 2.1 upwards.

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker